# Как загрузить и обработать данные в R

Tags: r

Загружаю данные `df_5.txt` вот ссылка https://yadi.sk/d/vOckRo-G0YQ2jg, но дата и время разделяются в разные столбцы.

```
#загрузка текстовых данных из файла
result <- read.table(file = "df_5.txt", row.names=NULL, fill = TRUE )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А надо в одном столбце что бы были. Вот такой формат y.m.d. h:m:s. в столбце 'date', на выходе получить временные ряды. Вот пример что должно получиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо указать корректный разделитель полей в функции `read.table`. В данном случае это `\t`. Далее столбец `Date` можно преобразовать из строкового вектора в `POSIXct` с помощью функции `strptime`. Пример кода с файлом по ссылке:

```r
> x <- read.table(tmp, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
> x$Date <- as.POSIXct(x$Date)
> str(x)
'data.frame':   7293 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Date : POSIXct, format: "2018-03-01 17:44:59" ...
 $ s_10 : int  0 -81 -267 -167 -91 -170 -170 -170 -170 -170 ...
 $ s_8  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ s_8_2: int  0 0 -186 -186 -186 -186 -186 -186 -186 -186 ...
 $ s_8_3: int  0 -81 -81 19 95 16 16 16 16 16 ...
 $ s_6  : int  0 -81 -81 19 95 16 16 16 16 16 ...
```